# find a sequence in string

Tags: python-3.x, string, file

Hi I've got problem set in cs50 and having difficulties as this is my first week in Python and I would be appreciate if you don't directly write an open answer but forward me to the right functions or method to use.

We've been given a long string sequence in a .txt file, one line and no white spaces. I have to find the longest consecutive sequence of words of given DNA string

example txt:
GGAGGCCAAAGTCTTGTGATATCGGGCAACTCCCCGGGAGGAACACAGGCCCACCGAAAACAGCTTGAAATGGGAAACGTTCCCGATCTACGCCGGGCCAGAGG

original text is around 5000 characters but it goes like the example below. My task is to find the longest consecutive sequences of 'AGATC' string.

lets say the first consequtive sequence is 23 times, after i kept reading and find another consequtive sequences in 34 times, I have to store the biggest number.

My problem is not to find a way to read and analyse a string in this way. I can read a string can find the total repetitive times and so on but finding the longest repetition is not making sense in every way I've tried. I thought C was hard but I can write this code with C so easily as I we can manipulate strings in so much way in C. At least in C there are ways to read in a size but as far as I see Python reads at once and there is no control over read. In Python it doesn't seem you can make much with, at least in my level of knowledge at the moment :/ Probably Python got one line solutions for this, please don't judge this is my 3rd day and 4th program in Python.

What functions or methods I should look to analyze a string in this way. I've watched videos for a similiar thing but for sequence of single character, not a string. Also bought the Python Crash Course to get some knowledge about the string manipulation but couldn't find anything related in this case. Also checked the Python documentation but obviously it's so much complicated for day 3 in Python.

Could anyone help me please.TIA

here is my not-working and not-making-sense code

```
import csv
import sys

#check the arguments count
if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    print("Usage: python dna.py data.csv sequence.txt")
    sys.exit(1)
#create a dictionary to store str results
SEQ = {
    "AGATC": 0,
    "AATG": 0,
    "TATC": 0
}

counter = 0 #keeps the the length of the sequence
seq = 0 #keeps the longest sequence
DNA = '' ## keeps the key of SEQ, "AGATC" etc.

#find the longest consecutive sequence of DNA
def findSEQ(file, DNA):   #get the sequences text file and the string of the key as parameters
    for DNA in (DNA, file):
        if file[i:i + len(DNA)] == DNA:  #if find a match
            counter += 1   #count up the sequence
        else:
            if counter > seq:    #if it's not a sequence the next thing it reads
                seq = counter
                counter = 0
                return seq
                seq = 0

#open sequence file and read
with open(sys.argv[2],'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    #find the longest sequence of AGATC
    findSEQ("AGATC", file)
    #update the seq dictionary
    SEQ["AGATC"] = seq
    #find the longest sequence of AATG
    findSEQ(file, "AATG")
    #update the seq dictionary
    SEQ["AATG"] = seq
    #find the longest sequence of TATC
    findSEQ(file, "TATC")
    #update the seq dictionary
    SEQ["TATC"] = seq

#open and read database
with open(sys.argv[1], "r") as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    #skip the first row
    next(reader)
    #compare the seq dictionary results with database
    for row in reader:
        seq1, seq2, seq3 = row[1], row[2], row[3]
        #if found any match print the name
        if SEQ[seq1] == row[1] and SEQ[seq2] == row[2] and SEQ[seq3] == row[3]:
            print(row[0])
        #otherwise print not found
        else:
            print("Not found any match.")
```

Comment: Have you considered using regex? You can find all matches of any length with the regex r'(AGATC)+', and then sort the result by length.

Comment: @AlonGadot  not tried that one, I thought it was only finding the total amount of sequences.I'll give a try, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To elaborate on my comment, please find the following example:

```
import re
text = 'GGAGGCCAAGATCAAGTCTTGTGATATCGGGCAACTCCCCGGGAAGATCAGATCAGATCGGAACACAGGCCCACCGAAAACAGCTTGAAGATCAATGGGAAACGTTCCCGATCTACGCCGGGCCAGAGG'
sequence = 'AGATC'
pattern = f'(?:{sequence})+'
findings = sorted(re.findall(pattern, text), key=len)
longest_sequence = len(findings[-1]) / len(sequence)
print(f'longest sequence: {longest_sequence}')
```

This program uses regex (regular expressions) to find sequences of the pattern you're looking for. It then sorts the findings by length (in an ascending order), allowing you to find the longest sequences in the last index of the list.

Comment: I've implemented this without adding other functions. But it finds the total number of how many 'AGATC' in the file. But my task is to find only the longest sequence which was 22 for the test case, but program founded 110.. Am I missing something (probably cos I'm fairly new) or should I try something else? TIA

Comment: import csv
import sys 
import re 

#check the arguments count 
if len(sys.argv) != 3:     
    print("Usage: python dna.py data.csv sequence.txt")     
    sys.exit(1) 

#create a dictionary to store str results 
SEQ = {     "AGATC": 0,     "AATG": 0,     "TATC": 0 }  

with open(sys.argv[2],'r') as file:     
text = file.read()        re.findall(r'(?:AGATC)+', text)     
findings = sorted(re.findall(r'(?:AGATC)+', text), key=len)     
print(f'longest sequence: {len(findings[-1])}')

Comment: Oh, I thought you wanted to find the length of that string. Just divide it by the length of your sought sequence - 110 / 5 = 22
I'll edit my answer

Comment: Also, I didn't copy your exact text example. Remember to replace it with your own.